# Align widget in one parent relative to a widget in another parent - Flutter

Tags: flutter, alignment

In my flutter project, I've the code structure as:

```
Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: statusViews,
        ),
        Row(
          children: textViews,
        )
      ],
    );
```

First row contains 4 Images with some Progress Bars in between them. And second row contains 4 Text for respective status images in first row. I want to center align text from second row relative to the image in first row.

[image]

So my basic question is: How can we align widget in one parent relative to a widget in another parent ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping each Row item in a column widget and placing the image and corresponding text in the column?  it should be streight forward to center everything from there.

Update:  looking at your code snippet, the Row children are a lists of widgets.  in the code section where you create the widget list, wrap each item in a column and include the appropriate text and alignment.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but the space between icon and progress was too large.

Answer (score -1):

For progress bar remove the text widget container.

```
body: Container(
    child: Column(children: [
      Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Column(children: [
              Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/ProfilePic.jpg"),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain)),
              Container(child: Text("Test"))
            ]),
          ]),
    ]),
  ),
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E2lG.png)